Shipping row random missing issue in the order details table in WooCommerce
I've been using a custom WooCommerce plugin that sets a fixed shipping value through a button click during the checkout process. While it mostly always works as expected, in about 2 out of every 20 orders, the shipping row itself is not visible in the order details table, confirmation emails, or the WooCommerce orders page after the order is placed.
Here's the code I'm using, and I hope someone can help identify the issue.
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Custom Shipping Value
 * Description: Customizations for WooCommerce.
 * Version: 1.0
 * Author: udd_ish
**/

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) or exit;

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_custom_scripts');
function enqueue_custom_scripts() {
    // Enqueue the custom JS file
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('distancecal-scripts', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'js/distancecal-scripts.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
    wp_localize_script('distancecal-scripts', 'ajax_object', array('ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));
}

function modify_shipping_cost($shipping_cost) {
    if ( isset($shipping_cost) ){
        WC()->session->set('shipping_cost', $shipping_cost);
        error_log("Shipping cost set to $shipping_cost in session");
    }
    return $shipping_cost;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_form_field_button', 'create_button_form_field_type', 10, 4 );
function create_button_form_field_type( $field, $key, $args, $value ){
    return sprintf('<p class="form-row %s" id="%s_field" data-priority="%s">
        <button type="%s" id="%s" class="%s">%s</button>
    </p>',
    implode(' ', $args['class']), esc_attr($key), $args['priority'] ? $args['priority'] : '', 
    $args['type'], esc_attr($key), $args['input-class'], $args['label'] );
}

add_action('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'insert_custom_button_in_billing_form');
function insert_custom_button_in_billing_form( $fields ) {
    $fields['billing']['custom-button'] = array(
        'type'         => 'button',
        'label'        => __('Calculate Delivery Fee'),
        'class'        =>  array('form-row-wide'),
        'input-class'  => 'button alt',
        'priority'     => 61, // <== Field location (after Street address fields)
    );
    return $fields;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label', 'display_only_shipping_method_price', 10, 2 );
function display_only_shipping_method_price( $label, $method ) {
    // HERE define your targeted rate id
    $targeted_rate_id = 'flat_rate:4';

    if ( $method->id === $targeted_rate_id && 0 < $method->cost ) {
        $label = str_replace( $method->label . ': ', '', $label);
    }
    return $label;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'shipping_package_rates_filter_callback', 100, 2 );
function shipping_package_rates_filter_callback( $rates, $package ) {
    // HERE define your targeted rate id
    $targeted_rate_id = 'flat_rate:4'; 
    
    if ( ! array_key_exists($targeted_rate_id, $rates) ) 
        return $rates;
    
    $new_cost = WC()->session->get('shipping_cost'); // Get new cost from WC sessions

    if ( ! empty($new_cost) ) {
        // Set shipping label empty
        $rates[$targeted_rate_id]->label = '';
        $rate = $rates[$targeted_rate_id];
        $cost = $rate->cost; // Set the initial cost in a variable for taxes calculations
        $rates[$targeted_rate_id]->cost = $new_cost; // Set the new cost

        $has_taxes = false; // Initializing
        $taxes     = array(); // Initializing
        foreach ($rate->taxes as $key => $tax_cost){
            if( $tax_cost > 0 ) {
                $tax_rate    = $tax_cost / $cost; // Get the tax rate conversion
                $taxes[$key] = $new_cost * $tax_rate; // Set the new tax cost in taxes costs array
                $has_taxes   = true; // There are taxes (set it to true)
            }
        }
        if( $has_taxes ) {
            $rates[$targeted_rate_id]->taxes = $taxes; // Set taxes costs array
        }
    } else {
        unset($rates[$targeted_rate_id]);
    }
    return $rates;
}




// PHP WP AJAX handler
add_action('wp_ajax_shipping_cost_update', 'shipping_cost_update_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_shipping_cost_update', 'shipping_cost_update_callback');
function shipping_cost_update_callback() {
    $price = 100;
    modify_shipping_cost($price);
    wp_die(); // Make sure to exit after handling the AJAX request
}


// Refresh shipping methods
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_review', 'checkout_update_refresh_shipping_methods' );
function checkout_update_refresh_shipping_methods() {
    if ( WC()->session->__isset('shipping_cost') ) {
        $packages = WC()->cart->get_shipping_packages();
        
        foreach ($packages as $package_key => $package ) {
             WC()->session->set( 'shipping_for_package_' . $package_key, false ); // Or true
        }
    }
}

// Remove the WC session variable once the order is created
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_order_created', 'remove_wc_session_shipping_cost_variable', 10, 1);
function remove_wc_session_shipping_cost_variable( ) {
    if ( WC()->session->__isset('shipping_cost') ) {
        WC()->session->__unset('shipping_cost');
    }
}

// (optional) Remove the WC Session variable on other pages than checkout
add_action('template_redirect', 'wc_session_shipping_cost_variable_only_on_checkout', 10, 1);
function wc_session_shipping_cost_variable_only_on_checkout() {
    if ( ! ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) ) {
        remove_wc_session_shipping_cost_variable();
    }
}

Here's the JS code
jQuery( function($) {
    // Add your custom JavaScript here
    $(document.body).on('click', '#custom-button', function() {
            
            $('#custom-button').text('Calculating Delivery Fee').prop('disabled', true);

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: ajax_object.ajaxurl,
                data: {
                    action: 'shipping_cost_update'
                },
                success: function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    $('#custom-button').text('Calculate Delivery Fee').prop('disabled', false);
                    $(document.body).trigger('update_checkout', { update_shipping_method: true });
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    // Handle AJAX error if needed
                    console.error('AJAX error:', error);
                    $('#custom-button').text('Calculate Delivery Fee').prop('disabled', false);
                    alert('Error calculating delivery fee. Please try again.');
                }
            });
        }
    });
});


Inspired by: Change WooCommerce Checkout shipping method cost from a WC Session variable

Simulate order that have it missing and debug.

hi @Snuffy I've tried several times to replicate the issue, but it happens very infrequently.

I think your problem comes from this $new_cost = WC()->session->get('shipping_cost') at the end you clear it if its set but then if you create a new order maybe it's missing so this if ( ! empty($new_cost) ) {} skips?  I would check if this is the case and add some error log points to see where it skips.

hi @LoicTheAztec thank you for your suggestion and i have added the link reference. could you please tell what could be the issue?

hi @LoicTheAztec i have debug the the code and noticed that $new_cost in shipping_package_rates_filter_callback is empty when the issue comes. but modify_shipping_cost function will set the value correctly(confirmed with debug line).

hi @Snuffy i did debug and noticed $new_cost in shipping_package_rates_filter_callback is empty when the issue comes. but modify_shipping_cost function will set the value correctly(confirmed with debug line)

@udd_ish Try to add to the shipping_cost_update_callback() function, WC()->cart->calculate_shipping(); at the end, just before wp_die();…

hi @LoicTheAztec thank you so much for your suggestion. I have added the line mentioned above. will check and let you know. thank you again.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
